# How to get IP address, prefix (or netmask) and gateways for active interfaces in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, nic

I'm trying to get the IP address, prefix (or netmask) and gateways for active interfaces in PowerShell.

I found these commands but cannot get all the information from the same command :

```
PS C:\> Get-NetIPConfiguration | ? { $_.NetAdapter.Status -ne "Disconnected" } | Select InterfaceAlias, IPv4Address , PrefixLength , IPv4DefaultGateway

InterfaceAlias IPv4Address   PrefixLength IPv4DefaultGateway
-------------- -----------   ------------ ------------------
LAN            {10.20.24.51}              {MSFT_NetRoute (InstanceID = ":8:8:8:9:55?@55;:8?:8??8;55;")}


PS C:\> Get-NetIPInterface -ConnectionState Connected -AddressFamily IPv4 | Get-NetIPAddress | Select  InterfaceAlias, IPv4Address , PrefixLength , IPv4DefaultGateway

InterfaceAlias              IPv4Address PrefixLength IPv4DefaultGateway
--------------              ----------- ------------ ------------------
LAN                         10.20.24.51           24
Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1 127.0.0.1              8



PS C:\>
```

I'm expecting this :

```
InterfaceAlias              IPv4Address   PrefixLength IPv4DefaultGateway
--------------              ---------   ------------ ------------------
LAN                         10.20.24.51           24 10.20.24.1
Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1 127.0.0.1              8 


PS C:\>
```

Comment: Change `Select ..., IPv4DefaultGateway` to `Select ..., @{Name='IPv4DefaultGateway';Expression={($_|Get-NetIPConfiguration).IPv4DefaultGateway.Nexthop}}`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Thank you for your answer :+1. The only inconvenience, though, is that this commands twice the time to run.